# Can i get any other report other than Extent report

Tags: selenium, testng, extentreports

Can i get any report name in Selenium, java, testng framework which will display only test case name and Status , excluding the test step results

Currently I'm using the Extent report, but will be getting the test step results also..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking at the default reports that TestNG generates ? (Emailable report and the plain vanilla html report) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the default TestNG report by using the listeners. See the section 6.2 in the documentation, http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html